# How to terminate the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, environment

I wanted to deploy react app with the help of docker environment on EBS. I kept all the values as default and created the environment but now I am facing this error. Now how can I terminate this environment and create a new one? Or how can I solve this error?

[image]

I deleted all the applications. Also tried to create IAM users but did not worked.

**Edit:**
I visited after one day to the elastic beanstalk environments and found out this. This means there are no active environments, right? And all the previous ones are deleted?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create missing IAM role `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` as explained in EB docs:

- [Creating an instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html#iam-instanceprofile-create)

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't delete the IAM instance profile used which was used to launch the environment. If it was accidentally deleted, you may need to create the instance profile with all the resource role that was attached to your elastic Beanstalk environment.